# MongoDB MapReduce producing different results for each document

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715543/mongodb-aggregation-unwind-group-project-query-combination), where I tried to solve this problem with the aggregation framework.  Unfortunately, I have to wait before being able to update this particular mongodb installation to a version that includes the aggregation framework, so have had to use MapReduce for this fairly simple pivot operation.

I have input data in the format below, with multiple daily dumps:

```
"_id" : "daily_dump_2013-05-23",
    "authors_who_sold_books" : [
        {
            "id" : "Charles Dickens",
            "original_stock" : 253,
            "customers" : [
                {
                   "time_bought" : 1368627290,
                   "customer_id" : 9715923
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "JRR Tolkien",
            "original_stock" : 24,
            "customers" : [
                {
                    "date_bought" : 1368540890,
                    "customer_id" : 9872345
                },
                {
                    "date_bought" : 1368537290,
                    "customer_id" : 9163893
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm after output in the following format, that aggregates across all instances of each (unique) author across all daily dumps:

```
{
    "_id" : "Charles Dickens",
    "original_stock" : 253,
    "customers" : [
        {
            "date_bought" : 1368627290,
            "customer_id" : 9715923
        },
        {
            "date_bought" : 1368622358,
            "customer_id" : 9876234
        },
        etc...
    ]
}
```

I have written this map function...

```
function map() {
  for (var i in this.authors_who_sold_books)
  {
    author = this.authors_who_sold_books[i];
    emit(author.id, {customers: author.customers, original_stock: author.original_stock, num_sold: 1});
  }
}
```

...and this reduce function.

```
function reduce(key, values) {
  sum = 0
  for (i in values)
  {
    sum += values[i].customers.length
  }
  return {num_sold : sum};
}
```

However, this gives me the following output:

```
{
  "_id" : "Charles Dickens",
  "value" : {
    "customers" : [
      {
        "date_bought" : 1368627290,
        "customer_id" : 9715923
      },
      {
        "date_bought" : 1368622358,
        "customer_id" : 9876234
      },
    ],
    "original_stock" : 253,
    "num_sold" : 1
  }
}
{ "_id" : "JRR Tolkien", "value" : { "num_sold" : 3 } }
{
  "_id" : "JK Rowling",
  "value" : {
    "customers" : [
      {
        "date_bought" : 1368627290,
        "customer_id" : 9715923
      },
      {
        "date_bought" : 1368622358,
        "customer_id" : 9876234
      },
    ],
    "original_stock" : 183,
    "num_sold" : 1
  }
}
{ "_id" : "John Grisham", "value" : { "num_sold" : 2 } }
```

The even indexed documents have the customers and original_stock listed, but an incorrect sum of num_sold.
The odd indexed documents only have the num_sold listed, but it is the correct number.

Could anyone tell me what it is I'm missing, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that the format of the output of the reduce function should be identical to the format of the map function (see [requirements for the reduce function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) for an explanation).

You need to change the code to something like the following to fix the problem, :

```
function map() {
  for (var i in this.authors_who_sold_books)
  {
    author = this.authors_who_sold_books[i];
    emit(author.id, {customers: author.customers, original_stock: author.original_stock, num_sold: author.customers.length});
  }
}

function reduce(key, values) {
  var result = {customers:[] , num_sold:0, original_stock: (values.length ? values[0].original_stock : 0)};
  for (i in values)
  {
    result.num_sold += values[i].num_sold;
    result.customers = result.customers.concat(values[i].customers);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I hope that helps.

*Note : the change `num_sold: author.customers.length` in the map function. I think that's what you want*